# Reload iFrame (same-domain) without changing `src=`

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, frame

I am dynamically creating iframe , which just contains content (no `src` attribute).

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML=  my_page_content;  
....
```

however, JS scripts (<`script src="....."` inside `my_page_content`) are not being loaded and I have to re-load scripts.

these methods wont help me to reload frame:

```
//this one emptyfies the iframe at all
iframeElement.src = iframeElement.src
//this one is not possible, because the `<script>` links are embedded in the content already.
var script = doc.createElement('script');  script.src = "jquery.min.js";
framebody.appendChild(script);
```

what are the solutions to force the iframe to load the included `scripts` in its html content? maybe I am attaching the content in a wrong way?

Comment: Are the scripts after the html they reference? Suspect issue is related to load events. Create a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: @charlietfl , thanks, I've found solution now, and have posted below.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've solved this was to write the body inside iframe using `write()` command:

```
var ifr = iframeElement.contentWindow.document;
ifr.open(); ifr.write("<body>"+ my_page_content +"</body>");    ifr.close();
```

neither `appendChild()` nor `.innerHTML` helped me.

Comment: Really? I think you would be better off using something else than `write()` if you can, I mean no `appendChild()` , no `iframeElement.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML=markeup` ?

Comment: @user10089632 none of them helped